# How do I exit my loop and display an answer

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

double baseDiamond, baseDiamondPrice, preDiamond, preDiamondPrice, baseDiamondCalc, finalECoins;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("What is your current Diamond Miner level? ");
preDiamondPrice = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter what diamondminer level ");
baseDiamondPrice = input.nextDouble();
while (baseDiamondPrice > 0) {
    baseDiamondPrice = ((baseDiamondPrice * 500000) + 1000000);
    baseDiamondPrice--;
}
while (preDiamondPrice > 0) {
    preDiamondPrice = ((preDiamondPrice * 500000) + 1000000);
    preDiamondPrice--;
}
baseDiamondCalc = (baseDiamondPrice - preDiamondPrice);


DecimalFormat dRemover = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println("You need " +dRemover.format(baseDiamondCalc)+ " ecoins for diamond miner level "+dRemover.format(baseDiamondPrice)+".");
    }}
```

why doesn't it work?

using the equation y = 1,000,000 + (500,000 * n)
I want the summation of all values of n less than n including 0.
e.g. if n = 3, I want 1,000,000 + (500,000 * 3) + 1,000,000 + (500,000 * 2) + 1,000,000 + (500,000 * 1) = 1,000,000 + (500,000 * 0).

As you can see in my code I want this to happen twice and then subtract one of the sums from the other.

Comment: Your control logic is incorrect. It will never exit either loop

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never exit the loop as-is because it is incrementing the loop control variable faster than it decrements.

```
while (baseDiamondPrice > 0) {
    baseDiamondPrice = ((baseDiamondPrice * 500000) + 1000000);
    baseDiamondPrice--;
}
```

If `baseDiamondPrice` is less than or equal to zero, you do not enter the loop.  If if it is any positive number, then in each loop iteration you add 1000000 and then subtract one.  That will never converge to zero and exit the loop.  It will also never arrive at your intended sum.  You should separate your control variable from your accumulator variable.

You can solve this assignment with a for loop with a loop control variable `i` for `i` from 0 to n and a separate accumulator variable to hold the running sum.

Comment: how do I fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your control logic is incorrect. It will never exit either loop
.You can modify it like below for both while loops.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

double baseDiamond, baseDiamondPrice, preDiamond, preDiamondPrice, baseDiamondCalc, finalECoins;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("What is your current Diamond Miner level? ");
preDiamondPrice = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter what diamondminer level ");
baseDiamondPrice = input.nextDouble();
double counter1 =baseDiamondPrice;
while (counter1 > 0) {
    baseDiamondPrice = ((baseDiamondPrice * 500000) + 1000000);
    counter1--;
}
double counter2 =preDiamondPrice;
while (counter2 > 0) {
    preDiamondPrice = ((preDiamondPrice * 500000) + 1000000);
    counter2--;
}
baseDiamondCalc = (baseDiamondPrice - preDiamondPrice);


DecimalFormat dRemover = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println("You need " +dRemover.format(baseDiamondCalc)+ " ecoins for diamond miner level "+dRemover.format(baseDiamondPrice)+".");
    }}
```

Comment: how do I fix this??:)

Comment: I have updated the code, and added two counters for each while loop. This code runs perfectly. You might need to check your business logic, as I didn't verify  it. Don't forget to accept/upvote, if you find it helpful